# Can Highcharts Bubblechart show the data-label of the top bubble when there are bubble overlapping?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, bubble-chart

The link below is the example of bubble overlapping, I want to know if I can show the data-label of the top overlapping bubble. In this case, show the label of the yellow bubble which is 'DE'.

[- Example of overlapping](http://jsfiddle.net/bj2etf7o/)

```
 $(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            type: 'bubble',
            plotBorderWidth: 1,
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },

        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Sugar and fat intake per country'
        },

        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: <a href="http://www.euromonitor.com/">Euromonitor</a> and <a href="https://data.oecd.org/">OECD</a>'
        },

        xAxis: {
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            title: {
                text: 'Daily fat intake'
            },
            labels: {
                format: '{value} gr'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                color: 'black',
                dashStyle: 'dot',
                width: 2,
                value: 65,
                label: {
                    rotation: 0,
                    y: 15,
                    style: {
                        fontStyle: 'italic'
                    },
                    text: 'Safe fat intake 65g/day'
                },
                zIndex: 3
            }]
        },

        yAxis: {
            startOnTick: false,
            endOnTick: false,
            title: {
                text: 'Daily sugar intake'
            },
            labels: {
                format: '{value} gr'
            },
            maxPadding: 0.2,
            plotLines: [{
                color: 'black',
                dashStyle: 'dot',
                width: 2,
                value: 50,
                label: {
                    align: 'right',
                    style: {
                        fontStyle: 'italic'
                    },
                    text: 'Safe sugar intake 50g/day',
                    x: -10
                },
                zIndex: 3
            }]
        },

        tooltip: {
            useHTML: true,
            headerFormat: '<table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><th colspan="2"><h3>{point.country}</h3></th></tr>' +
                '<tr><th>Fat intake:</th><td>{point.x}g</td></tr>' +
                '<tr><th>Sugar intake:</th><td>{point.y}g</td></tr>' +
                '<tr><th>Obesity (adults):</th><td>{point.z}%</td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            followPointer: true
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '{point.name}'
                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            data: [
                { x: 50, y: 50, z: 50, name: 'BE', country: 'Belgium', color:'red' },
                { x: 50, y: 51, z: 50, name: 'DE', country: 'Germany', color:'yellow' },
                { x: 100, y: 100, z: 50, name: 'DE', country: 'Germany' }]
        }]

    });
});
```

Comment: Only DE should be printed in that place? How about BE, should not be there or misplaced?

Comment: This setting is preventing the label overlapping, so only one label is suppose to show.

Comment: Is there a solution for this? I have the same problem myself. I have found how to bring the actual point forward, but the point's label remains hidden. It would be great if there was a way to bring labels to the top in the same manner as bringing a graphic to the top (by using the `toFront()` method).